# Database remediation in GW cloud

Tags: guidewire

How to establish Integration between Guidewire xCenter with onPrem databases ?

Can we try with DB replica between onPrem database to GW cloud Database instances or should we try ... Extracting onPrem Database data to local file and then use file based Integration in GW cloud ?

Answer (score 1):

In the GWCP you can't access any DB directly from the xCenters. It goes against the Cloud standards.
What you would have to do is either

1. Build an igApp (IntegrationGatewayApplication) that would access your onPrem data - however this isn't the best approach as you would have to open a tunnel to your DB directly.
2. Build an onPrem microservice and expose via RestAPI data from your onPrem DB and then access this API from either igApp or even xCenter directly using the RestClientAPI toolkit
3. Build your onPrem data replicas in your own AWS account and expose a nearby AWS service - this way you are staying compliant with all the GWCP Cloud Standards as even if you access for example DynamoDB directly from the igApp/xCenter you are doing this all through APIs

The third option as a variation where you can use the mentioned file extract and placing it on the S3 bucket but the question is if reading files directly would really be optimal as it's typically not an indexed structure